# Show line number in TeXnicCenter

Tags: texniccenter, line-numbering

i want to see line numbers, i read that i could do that from  `Tools ->Options -> Editor -> Show line numbers`  but I don't have the Show line numbers option in my version of TeXnicCenter. Is there a way I can select something that will make it active and appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current version 2.02 stable (64bit) you can activate this feature in the menu `View` -> `Line numbers`, or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>.

[image]